# Error in Rscript: "Error in system("tail -n1010 EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt | cut -f2", intern = TRUE) : 'tail' not found"

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the following script on R, but I get an error that I do not understand. The script is supposed to parse a movie script which is in txt format.

```
setwd("C:/Users/name/Desktop/star wars")

# read episode IV script in R (this is a character vector)
sw = readLines("StarWars_EpisodeIV_script.txt")

# inspect first 70 lines
# you'll see that the first dialogue is from THREEPIO in line 52
sw[1:70]

# command to extract character name (just for demo purposes)
substr(sw[52], 21, nchar(sw[52]))
# command to extract dialogue text (just for demo purposes)
substr(sw[53], 11, nchar(sw[53]))

# we need these auxiliary strings to help us
# extract character names and their dialogues
b10 = "          "
b20 = "                    "

# how many lines in input file
nlines = length(sw)

# let's parse the entire script while extracting only the names of the
# characters and their dialogues. The output file is EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt

# write first line in output file
writeLines("STAR WARS - EPISODE 4: STAR WARS", "EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt")

# the first 50 lines don't contain dialogues
# start reading at line 50
i = 50

# while loop to extract character and dialogues
# you may get some errors, just ignore them and re-run
# the while loop as many times as needed
while (i <= nlines)
{
  # if empty line
  if (sw[i] == "") i = i + 1  # next line
  # if text line
  if (sw[i] != "")
  {
    # if script description
    if (substr(sw[i], 1, 1) != " ") i = i + 1   # next line
    if (nchar(sw[i]) < 10) i = i + 1  # next line
    # if character name
    if (substr(sw[i], 1, 20) == b20) 
    {
      if (substr(sw[i], 21, 21) != " ")
      {
        tmp_name = substr(sw[i], 21, nchar(sw[i], "bytes"))
        cat("\n", file="EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt", append=TRUE)
        cat(tmp_name, "", file="EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt", sep="\t", append=TRUE)
        i = i + 1        
      } else {
        i = i + 1
      }
    }
    # if dialogue
    if (substr(sw[i], 1, 10) == b10)
    {
      if (substr(sw[i], 11, 11) != " ")
      {
        tmp_diag = substr(sw[i], 11, nchar(sw[i], "bytes"))
        cat(tmp_diag, file="EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt", append=TRUE)
        i = i + 1
      } else {
        i = i + 1
      }
    }
  }
}


# =====================================================================
# Creating data table "SW_EpisodeIV.txt"
# =====================================================================

# how many lines in output file
system("wc -l EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt")

# get vector of character names 
SW4_chars = system("tail -n1010 EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt | cut -f1", intern=TRUE)
# get vector of dialogue lines
SW4_diags = system("tail -n1010 EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt | cut -f2", intern=TRUE)

# check character names
table(SW4_chars)
# remove voices
SW4_chars = gsub("'S VOICE", "", SW4_chars)

# join characters and dialogues in one table
SW4 = cbind(character=SW4_chars, dialogue=SW4_diags)

# save SW4 in file 'SW_EpisodeIV.txt'
write.table(SW4, file="SW_EpisodeIV.txt")

# if you want to check the data table
A = read.table("SW_EpisodeIV.txt")
head(A)
tail(A)
```

The error comes up when I run the following lines

```
SW4_chars = system("tail -n1010 EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt | cut -f1", intern=TRUE)
# get vector of dialogue lines
SW4_diags = system("tail -n1010 EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt | cut -f2", intern=TRUE)
```

The error says

Error in system("tail -n1010 EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt | cut -f2", intern = TRUE) :
'tail' not found

I'm not sure what the error means.

Comment: The `system()` function sends commands to the operating system. What OS are you running? It looks from your `setwd()` that you're running Windows, but `tail` is a Unix command so it's not going to work. There is no reason to use system commands like `wc -l`, `tail` and `cut` from R - it has built ins for all of these (in fact it is pretty much built around all these).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm using Windows. Could you help to rewrite the line that gives the error? I found the code online and wanted to use it on a different movie script, I'm not that familiar with R.

Comment: Ensure that you have downloaded and installed Rtools from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and be sure that you have your path set up to invoke `tail` and other utilities (or else use the absolute path to it in your system statement).  On my Windows system `Sys.which("tail")` gives `"C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\tail.exe"`

Comment: If you're not that familiar with R then I think the advice to get the Unix commands working in your Windows environment is going to be the path of least resistance. I just checked my Windows system and `tail` is in fact installed - I didn't realise it was included with Rtools.

Comment: I downloaded and installed Rtools and I get the same output when I test Sys.which("tail"). Now the error is gone but I get a warning : Warning message:
In system("tail -n1010 EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt | cut -f1", intern = TRUE) :
  running command 'tail -n1010 EpisodeIV_dialogues.txt | cut -f1' had status 1

Comment: By "same output", do you mean that `Sys.which("tail")` is empty? If so, realize after you install Rtools, you need to (a) restart R/RStudio, and if that alone doesn't work, then (b) add Rtools to your `PATH` (OS-level thing, search windows for `Edit the system environment variables`) and then restart R and RStudio _again_. After that, verify that `Sys.which("tail")` and `Sys.which("cut")` are both not empty.

Comment: But ... then again, `system` does not do piped commands well. Try `shell("tail -n1010 Epi... | cut -f1")` instead.

Comment: With "same output" I meant the output that @G.Grothendieck got when Sys.which("tail") was run on their laptop. But changing system to shell solved the problem, thanks!